# Detected package downgrade for Boilerplate Application(.NET Core 3.1)

Tags: .net-core, aspnetboilerplate, .net-core-3.0

I'm trying to open my Boilerplate Application(.NET Core 3.1)in **VSCode** in Linux but below exception, keep appeared for me. Is there any difference between .NET Core for Linux and for Windows or What is the problem?

```
Detected package downgrade: Abp.ZeroCore from 5.7.0 to 5.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
```

Comment: If you are satisfied by the answer (the way that is phrased, and you find it helpful) please upvote the answer. It is different to mark as best answer and upvote an answer. By upvoting you help the answer stand out and help the community to solve this problem in an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not related to the OS that you run your application.

As stated in the error message there a downgrade in one of your nuget packages.

Go to your Boilerplate.csproj and try to manually set the version of `Abp.ZeroCore` nuget package from `5.1.0` that it is currently to `5.7.0`.